# Unknown property name when using media queries with React & Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get any media queries working with React.js and Bootstrap 4, anything I type outside the media query will work though. In chrome inspector anything in media queries show up as 'Unknown property name'. What am I doing wrong here?

[image: Chrome Output]

I have included the bootstrap 4 CDN JS dependencies inside index.html.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
 return (
  <div className='App'>
   <div className='container'>
    <h1 className='my-custom-color'>This is my app</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

```css
.my-custom-color {
 color: red;
 text-align: right;
 @media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta
   name="description"
   content="Web site created using create-react-app"
  />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <link
   rel="stylesheet"
   href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
   crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
  <title>React App</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
   integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
   crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
   integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
   crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
   src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
   integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
   crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normal css doesn't support nested media queries. The style file you provided looks like it's a `scss` file which hasn't been compiled to `css`, so the browser doesn't understand its syntax.

**To manually convert it to css**

```
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .my-custom-color {
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem! I'm very new to CSS.